# Comparing two directory for equalities

Tags: linux, perl, md5

Problem: Two separate directories with files. Seeing if they are different in terms of content, file system inode values(maybe?), etc.

I was wondering if there are any unix command that does this?

Or do I have to write, maybe a perl script, that goes and loop through each file content and perform MD5 hash content and then compare

or any quick solutions??

Comment: Can't `diff(1)` already do that?

Comment: If there are two directories, they are guaranteed to be on different inodes. What do you really want to do?

Comment: @Flimzy that's only one part of "Seeing if they are different in terms of content, file system inode values(maybe?), etc."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly what `diff` was made for! Use `-r` to do a recursive diff.

```
diff -r dir1 dir2
```

Options you may want:

```
   -q, --brief
          report only when files differ

   -u, -U NUM, --unified[=NUM]
          output NUM (default 3) lines of unified context
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diff -Nur dir1 dir2
```

The -N option tells diff to treat the absent files as empty.